# Warning: move_uploaded_file() failed to open stream

Tags: php, file-upload

I am trying to upload file on ftp.

here is my code

```
    $jname= "Accounts of Biotechnology Research";
    if (!is_dir('/Trade/upload/ '.$jname)) {

        mkdir('/Trade/upload/ '.$jname);   // line 63
    }
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["submission_file"]["tmp_name"],    "/Trade/upload/$jname/" . $dup_name );    // line 67
```

Trade is a folder inside public_html folder.

When i am uploading a file it gives me a warning like,

```
Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: No such file or directory in /home/my_username/public_html/Trade/upload.php on line 63

Warning: move_uploaded_file(/Trade/upload/Accounts of Biotechnology Research/76164762-sm.pdf) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/my_username/public_html/Trade/upload.php on line 67

Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/tmp/phphZXp0O' to '/Trade/upload/Accounts of Biotechnology Research/76164762-sm.pdf' in /home/my_username/public_html/Trade/upload.php on line 67
```

Comment: space on `'/Trade/upload/ '` is typo?

Comment: Might be you don't have that directory Trade/upload or you don't have a write permission there.

Comment: Do you have a directory `/Trade/upload/` already created?

Comment: yes i have a upload directory under trade

Comment: /Trade/upload/ after that you are appending a variable $jname that is again a directory make sure it exist and have permission.

Comment: Is your trade directory under website root folder? Or it is in root of file system?

Comment: @chandresh_cool  if $jname directory is not there,then it should be created through mkdir().but it doesn't creat.

Comment: there is a problem you don't have a write permission to either Trade or upload. Give it write permission.

Comment: @NiraliJoshi you should have sudo permission to change write permission of the directories. Basically we use ssh to change it using chmod command like chmod 775 -R directoryname

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First:
You have a space here `mkdir('/Trade/upload/ '.$jname);`. Suppose you should have `mkdir('/Trade/upload/'.$jname);` (same for is_dir)

Second:
Ensure that you can write into `Trade/upload` directory.

Third (and I suppose that is the real problem):

It looks like you are trying to upload into a directory with full path:
`/home/my_username/public_html/Trade/upload/`, but your code will try to create a directory with full path:
`/Trade/upload/`. 
You need to change

```
 if (!is_dir('/Trade/upload/ '.$jname)) {    
     mkdir('/Trade/upload/ '.$jname);   // line 63
 }
```

to

```
 if (!is_dir('upload/'.$jname)) {    
     mkdir('upload/'.$jname);   // line 63 (or maybe there should be Trade/upload, but suppose current working dir will be /home/my_username/public_html/Trade, so only upload/)
 }
```

Another option is to force [`mkdir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) to create directories recursively:

```
 mkdir('/Trade/upload/'.$jname, 0755, true);
```

But in that case, files will be uploaded into `/Trade/upload/...` instead of `/home/my_username/public_html/Trade/upload/...`

Comment: in my case permissions issue

Answer (score 4):

There are two things you should be aware of based on the error messages you received. I'm guessing `/Trade` isn't the root path on your machine since it's clear in the error that your actual path is `/home/my_username/public_html/Trade/`, so the first adjustment should be

```
$root_path = "/home/my_username/public_html/Trade/upload/";
```

The second adjustment I'd suggest is that you avoid pathnames with space in them:

```
$jname= "Accounts of Biotechnology Research"; //could be changed to
$jname= "Accounts_of_Biotechnology_Research"; //$jname = str_replace(" ","-",$jname)    OR
$jname= "Accounts-of-Biotechnology-Research"; //$jname = str_replace(" ","-",$jname)
```

Finally take note of the space character on the following lines, they affect you final result:

```
if (!is_dir('/Trade/upload/ '.$jname)) {   //AND
    mkdir('/Trade/upload/ '.$jname);
}
```

Note the [space] between `upload/ '.$jname` in both strings.